Getting error when trying to install Pandas using pip
I am trying to install Pandas.
I did:
pip install pandas

And I tried other versions:
pip install pandas=2.2.1

Always the same error:
root@thinkpad:/# pip install pandas==2.2.1
Collecting pandas==2.2.1
  Downloading pandas-2.2.1.tar.gz (4.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 4.4/4.4 MB 12.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [204 lines of output]

I am on a lightweight Debian 12, using Python 3.13. The latest beta release, I upgraded pip, and checked these as well:
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel    
sudo apt install build-essential libatlas-base-dev

The problem always persists; any help is welcome.

Which version of Python 3 are you on?

python 3.13 the 3rd beta 0b3, I installed it and trying to setup my whole environment to test it. started with numpy it installed fine, but then I am facing issues with pandas, the OS is a lightweight fresh install of debian that I try for the first time, I do not know which component is causing these issues. Anyone who encountered similar problems may know which python or linux component needs to be installed, updated or fixed ...

You might want to try with Python 3.12 on a virtual environment. The official support documentation for Pandas does not mention Python 3.13. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html#python-version-support

I am trying to see the speed improvement in the new python 3.13 that has been released as beta for months for developers, I hope there is a way to get around these errors and test pandas on it.

And what are those 204 lines of output? I'd expect them to contain the error message.

Here is all the output @CherryDT :
https://codefile.io/f/CuM31LWy9x

@ElyesLounissi its no use, no one here will be able to single-handedly update pandas and its dependencies to be compatible with a beta python version. You will need to wait for the lib to be officially compatible. Only then can you also make meaningful benchmarks

As of now, python 3.13 support is an open issue in the pandas github so it simply does not work yet. Wait for the pandas devs to have at least a pandas beta version ready.
